# Best Way to update PHP Variable?

Tags: php

I am currently having some issues with updating a PHP variable without refreshing the page.

In my situation the code will count the products and if there are none it won't shoot anything out. If the quantity of $total is 1 or greater it will display the amount.

```
<?php 
     $total = count_products(); 
     if ($total == 0) { 
        echo " "; 
     } else { 
        echo $total;  
     }
?>
```

Now what I am having trouble with is how to update that variable. If I were to add a product, I would not see the updated result until refreshing the page completely. Is there a nice way to update the $total without having to refresh the page?

Comment: PHP is a server-side language. You'll need to use something like JavaScript and XHR to do something like this.

Comment: Ajax would be the key here, update a div with the correct amount...

Comment: The lifetime of a PHP variable is the execution of the PHP script on the server. When you see the HTML page in browser the variable is already gone. "Updating a variable without refreshing the page" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: is there a way to use count_products(); in ajax or javascript to update? Not sure where to start

Comment: AJAX means you make a request to the server without reloading the current page. It happens in Javascript. The script requested on the server usually output JSON (it's easy to work with it in Javascript because it is a native format, there is no need for parsers). The Javascript uses the information it receives through AJAX to update the content of the current page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ajax to do that for you without refreshing page

Basic example here

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).on("click", ".thebutton", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();   
    $("#result").load(location.href+ ' #my');
  });

</script>

<button href="#" class="thebutton"> add product button</button>


<div id="result">
<div id="my">

<?php 

//echo time for demonstration
echo date('a:i:s'); 

?>

<!-- lets say this is where you echo your total -->
<?php 
     $total = count_products(); 
     if ($total == 0) { 
        echo " "; 
     } else { 
        echo $total;  
     }
?>

</div>
</div>
```

Hope this would be of some help to you